# if cookie does not exist redirect user external url django

Tags: django, jwt

I have **BaseContext** view and other templateView. Token is created inside the template. I also checking the token cookie exists if not I redirect user to this url--> https://testdomain.com/get_token?origin=http://localhost:8000

```
class BaseContext(View):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        request = self.request

        if request.COOKIES.get('token') is not None:
            token = request.COOKIES.get('token')
            bla bla bla 
            return context
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('https://testdomain.com/get_token?origin=http://localhost:8000')
```

and I have another view which inherited from basecontext

```
class Services(BaseContext, TemplateView):
    template_name = "services.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'service_active': 'Active'})
        return context
```

When I tried to load page, I got an error, like this, **'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'update'**

Comment: get_context_data should always return context and in this case you are sometimes returning HttpResponseRedirect hence error. This is not proper place to inject redirection

Comment: @iklinac how can I solve this issue? do you have an idea?